# What is the meaning of the 9 sacred threads in janoi?

Tags: yagnopavitam

I am soon going to undertake Upanayana(Yagnopavitam) and I was researching and I couldn't find any straight answer to my question and I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sacred thread is not considered just as an ordinary thread. Before wearing one, it has to undergo a process called Samskara, which is a purificatory ritual that is aimed at invoking the presence of various deities on the 9 threads and the 3 knots.

The relevant Mantras can be found on page 55 of the prayoga book called ["Nitya Karma Puja Prakasha"](https://ia802504.us.archive.org/34/items/HindiBookNityaKarmPoojaPrakashCompletebyGitaPress/Hindi%20Book-Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash(Complete)by%20Gita%20Press.pdf).

> [image]
>
> *Transliteration*
>
> Prathamotantau Om omkaram avahayami | Dvitiyatantau agni avahayami | 
>   ..... **Prathamagranthau Om Brahmane namah, Brahmanam avahayami |
>   Dvitiyagranthau Om Vishnave namah, Vishum avahayami | Trityagranthau
>   Om Rudraya namah, Rudram avahayami** ||

So, what these mantras say is that in the Yajnopavita there are 9 interwined threads and 3 knots. In the 9 threads Om, Agni, Sarpa, Soma .. Surya, Viswadevas are invoked.

And, on the 3 knots (Granthi), the Trinities are invoked viz - Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra in that order.

Translations of the bold portions are as follows:

> Prathamagranthau Om Brahmane namah, Brahmanam avayami - In the first
>   knot, Om salutations to Lord Brahma, I am inviting the presence of
>   Brahma on this knot.

Similarly for the other two knots.

Therefore, the 3 knots represent the Trinities - Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra and their presence on the sacred thread.

Comment: I always had this doubt, so those who wear janoi can't eat nonveg even they eat earlier right

Comment: No it is not exactly like that. Many people used to wear the thread and still ate meat. But in todays time Brahmins (who mostly wear the thread) usually don't eat non-veg.@user2225190 You have to follow the tradition of ur family and region.

Comment: Nice answer. Swami Vivekananda says 3 knots are for controlling Body mind Sences and another acharya 3 gunas. Are there any references for these ?

Comment: Not sure must be there in some scriptures @SethuSrivatsaKoduru